# std::string to LPBYTE and RegEnumValueA

Tags: c++, registry, type-conversion

What is the proper way to cast std::string to LPBYTE to make this code work?

```
string Name;
string Value;
RegEnumValueA(hKey, 0, const_cast<char*>(Name.c_str()), &dwSize, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)const_cast<char*>(Value.c_str()), &dwSize2);
```

When I try to user this code everythins is okey with the string name, but there's a bad pointer error in the string value

Comment: You can't write to the buffer retrieved by `c_str()`.

Comment: You can use `&Value[0]` with C++11 but you are better off with `vector<>` here I think.

Comment: Make sure not to overwrite the null character if you choose a string, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way od getting `std::string` with data you want

```
//alloc buffers on stack
char buff1[1024];
char buff2[1024];

//prepare size variables
DWORD size1=sizeof(buff1);
DWORD size2=sizeof(buff2);

//call
RegEnumValueA(hKey, 0, buff1, &size1, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)buff2, &size2);

//"cast" to std::string
std::string Name(buff1);
std::string Value(buff2);
```

Comment: Your string construction needs a second iterator, not a size.

Comment: However it was incorrect, since the string returned from RegEnumValueA is null terminated, the "size1" and "size2" fields are left unchanges. I modified the strin construction therefore.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I'm used to constructing containers with iterator pairs, since I don't think any others take an iterator and a size. For some reason, I forgot about the null-terminated string constructor as well.

Comment: Strings returned from registry functions are not guaranteed to be null terminated. It's trivial to see that is the case by putting in a value that does not have a null character.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer parameters should point to valid buffers that will be modified by a function. The `c_str()` of an unitialized string does not point to anything valid.

Use char buffers instead of a `string`s. This is a very good case of const_cast<> being totally uncalled for.

```
char Name[200], Value[200]; //Sizes are arbitrary
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(Name), dwSize2 = sizeof(Value);

RegEnumValueA(hKey, 0, Name, &dwSize, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)Value, &dwSize2);
```

Comment: This is fine, until you need to decide at runtime how but the buffers are. At which point `vector<>` is the answer.

Comment: Why would you prefer new over vector?!

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to "cast" `std::string` as you said, you could consider the following piece of code. It should work on any `std::string` implementation I know, but still it is a bit "hacky" and I'd not recommend it.

```
string Name(1024, ' ');
string Value(1024, ' ');
DWORD dwSize=Name.size();
DWORD dwSize2=Value.size();

RegEnumValueA(hKey, 0, const_cast<char*>(&Name[0]), &dwSize, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)const_cast<char*>(&Value[0]), &dwSize2);
```

Comment: Thanks it seems the best way to do what I wanted:)